# Как пересылать сообщения из группы telegram ботом?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Использую библиотеку telebot, я хочу сделать так, чтобы все сообщения, которые пишут пользователи в группу, автоматически пересылались мне. Я пытался найти то, как возможно это реализовать на библиотеке telebot, но нашёл только это:

```
    import telebot
token = '*****'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
TO_CHAT_ID = '*****'
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Этот код пересылает мне сообщения только тех людей, которые пишут лично боту. Но я бы хотел чтобы бот пересылал мне все сообщения, которые были отправлены в группу различными пользователями, конечно же в этой группе бот состоит.

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему так. Нужно просто сделать бота администратором группы, чтобы он пересылал сообщения других пользователей, а не только тех, которые пишут ему лично.